# Django Email settings without using From Address

Tags: python, django, email, django-forms

Here is my settings.py

```
 EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
 EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
 EMAIL_HOST_USER = "mygmail@gmail.com"
 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mypassword"
 EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

and view.py code

`From='someemail@mail.com'
send_mail(Subject,Message, From, [To])`

every time when a mail is sent it shows `mygmail@gmail.com` ,but i need it show `someemail@mail.com` ,how to fix this??

Comment: use EmailMessage() instead of send_mail()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add your "someemail@mail.com" to your gmail account?

Google have a procedure to allow their SMTP to send email as an other, they require you can find a code they send to this given email.

Otherwise it's normal.

(Security way to avoid malicious users tu use google's SMTP to send email as "barack.obama@whitehouse.gov")

Answer (score 0):

Google only allows you to send email from addresses you have registered on your Gmail account. So someemail@mail.com will not work unless that's a registered gmail account. Though I suspect you are trying to use it as mask from some user in your app to send mail as themselves.

An alternate way to do it is to use something other than Gmail (such as Mailgun, Sendgrid, etc). For best practices, send the email from a legitimate registered email address, but utilize the reply-to field for custom emails.